# migrate from glassfish 3 to tomcat 7

Tags: tomcat, glassfish, migration

i'am using netbeans IDE 7.3.1 and i have a "web application project" and am using with it glassfish 3 (JMS project), i want to migrate to tomcat 7 now; i installed tomcat 7 succeessfuly ,(i can run or stop it ) and the problem is that when  acces the project properties -> run --> servers i cant find tomcat in the list ! i can only choose glassfish
and when i create a new project i can select tomcat from the list

please help me how to run my project with tomcat 7 instead of glassfish 3

Answer (score 0):

Right click your existing project and click "Properties." Go to "Targed Runtimes" and add Tomcat 7 as a new Runtime Environment. You should be able to deploy your project with Tomcat after this.

**EDIT:** The "Targed Runtimes" section in Properties  is located here:
[image]

Comment: cant find target runtimes in the project properties

Comment: i dont have this windows, here is a screenshot from my project properties http://imageup.fr/uploads/1373911736.jpeg  are you using netbeans like me ? thanks for your answer

Comment: It appears I misread your question - I provided the solution if you were using eclipse. I'm not familiar with NetBeans, but you can easily copy your project over to a new one if the new one can deploy with Tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

In the services section on the left pane , click servers there opens glassfish server and tomcat,
To switch from glassfish to tomcat:

1. right click on the glassfish server, then click stop
2. right click on the tomcat server, then click start.

To switch from tomcat to glassfish :

1. right click on the tomcat server, then click stop
2. right click on the glassfish server, then click start